# How do I have my Bot respond with arguments?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

So I've built a Telegram bot, which can receive the following commands:

- `/list`
- `/info 123`

This works great, as I can catch `/info` and pass the additional arguments as ints. But, sadly, the Telegram clients don't see `/info 123` as a complete command, but just the `/info` part. Is there a way to make it recognize the entirety of the command as the command?

I've tried Markdown-ing it: `[/info 123](/info 123)`, but no joy. Is this possible?

Comment: Show us some code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've reached out to @BotSupport with the same question, and he/they/it responded swiftly with the following answer:

> Hi, at the moment it is not possible to highlight parameters of a command. I any case, you may can find a workaround if you use correct custom keyboards ;)
>    — @BotSupport

Custom keyboards may be an option for someone, but not for me. The solution I've gone for is to give the command as `/info123`. As the bot receives all `/` commands, I check if the received command starts with `info`, and if so, I remove the `info` part. I convert the remaining string/int to arguments, and pass that along to the relevant command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do you check the command name, I am trying to find a way to catch all commands then to parse them. Thank you!

Comment: @com that's all dependent on the framework you're using.

Comment: @ortonomy No, you don't. Registering commands with BotFather only make them show on user interface as a list when someone types "/", but you can implement commands that aren't listed - just don't register them in BotFather. Your bot will answer the commands regardless.

Answer (score 14):

If you mean to pass the `123` as an argument for your command `info` and if you happen to use the [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/), then here's how you do it:

```
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', SayHello, pass_args=True))
```

According to the documentation: `pass_args` Determines whether the handler should be passed the arguments passed to the command as a keyword argument called `args`. It will contain a list of strings, which is the **text following the command split on single or consecutive whitespace** characters. Default is False.

Comment: I get what you're saying - but if you provide feedback to the user, with a list of commands, you can't highlight or make the full `/info 123` clickable. It'll just be `/info` that gets highlighted and thus sent.

Comment: @Mave so you want a list of all the possible arguments, hardcoded so that they appear when the user clicks the `/` icon on the chat? I believe the only way to do that is to actually hardcode them as separate commands with an delimiter between the arguments such as `/info_123` or `/info_456`. Those should actually appear in the dropdown list but they don't actually accept arguments, they are just two different commands that call the same underlying method with different arguments.

Answer (score 6):

you can use [**RegexHandler()**](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.regexhandler.html#telegram.ext.RegexHandler.pattern) to do this.

Here is an **example**

```
def info(bot, update):
  id = update.message.text.replace('/info_', '')
  update.message.reply_text(id, parse_mode='Markdown')


def main():
  updater = Updater(TOKEN)
  updater.dispatcher.add_handler(RegexHandler('^(/info_[\d]+)$', info))
  updater.start_polling()
```

**Usage**

The command `/info_120` will return `120`
and `/info_007` will return `007`

**UPDATE**
for newer versions, you may use this method instead!

```
MessageHandler(filters.Regex(r'^(/info_[\d]+)$'), info)
```

Comment: Aah, fair point, that would have been a good way to do it as well! Thanks :).

Comment: and now MessageHandler(filters.Regex(r'^(/info_[\d]+)$'), info)

Answer (score 4):

To get the argument of command you don't even need to use `pass_args` as said [Moein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122030/6687545) you can simply get it from `context.args` look at [Github page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Types-of-Handlers#commandhandlers-with-arguments). So you can pass as many arguments as you want and you will get a list of arguments! Here is an example from Github.

```
def start_callback(update, context):
  user_says = " ".join(context.args)
  update.message.reply_text("You said: " + user_says)

...

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_callback))
```

Answer (score 4):

### ForceReply

> Upon receiving a message with this object, Telegram clients will display a reply interface to the user (act as if the user has selected the bot's message and tapped 'Reply'). This can be extremely useful if you want to create user-friendly step-by-step interfaces without having to sacrifice privacy mode.

#### a simple shot

[image]

In this case, a user should send a valid number with `/audio` command (e.g. `/audio 3`, if they forgot it, we can inform and force them to do so.

source:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly rudimentary way of creating kwargs from user input.

Unfortunately, it does require the user to be aware of the fields that can be used as parameters, but if you can provide informative response when the user doesnt provide any detectable kwarg style messages then you could probably make a better experience.

As I say, extremely rudimentary idea, and would probably be achieved faster with the regex filters available. And this would be much more reliable when checking input from the user of the "pesky" variety.

The script relies on `||` delimiter preceeding the command and as is shown will trim any extra characters like new lines and spaces

You can remove the extra check for `commit` as this is provided in order to tell the bot that you want to save your input to the database explicitly.

```
def parse_kwargs(update):
    commit = False
    kwargs = {}
    if update.message:
        for args in update.message.text.split('||')[1:]:
            for kw_pair in args.split(','):
                key, value = kw_pair.split('=')
                if key.strip() != 'commit':
                    kwargs[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                elif key.strip() == 'commit' and value.strip().lower() == 'true':
                    commit = True
    return kwargs, commit
```